# Add indentation for long text in the kendo multiselect dropdown to differentiate that its a single record

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I need to add an indentation while displaying the data in the kendo multiselect dropdown.

Below is the code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
  .Name("OrderSelection")
  .DataTextField("OrderData")
  .DataValueField("OrderId")
  .AutoClose(false)
  .Placeholder("Select Orders...")
  .Height((wndHeight - 260))
  .Events(e =>
            {
              e.Select("onOrderSelect").Deselect("onOrderDeselect");
              e.Open("validateDates");
              
            })
  .DataSource(source =>
                {
                  source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                  read.Action("ReadOrderItemsByDate", "CustomNotes").Data("orderSelectionReuestData");
                                })
                  .ServerFiltering(false);
                })
)
```

[image]

In the above image I want to add a space before the text skills so the user will know that it's not a separate record but one single record.

Answer (score 0):

That might be hard to do. Regardless, I think you need to use an ItemTemplate. This is equivalent to what you get by default and just renders the data item:

```
.ItemTemplate("#= data #")
```

You can put whatever html you want in there though. For example wrap it in a div with a class:

```
.ItemTemplate("<div class='add-border'>#= data #</div>")
```

You can then target that class with css to add a border, padding, highlighting or a background color to the div. Or just add styling inline if you wish. That is my suggestion, add some kind of border or background to distinguish each item.

Comment: Tried using item template , however i am not getting how to add space for the (2nd)row  ,i am using below code:                                                                                                      .ItemTemplate("<span # if (data.OrderData.length > 50) { #class='break-row'# } #>#: OrderData #</span>")                                                                                                                  .break-row{
       
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        
        }     , But not sure what to write in css Class to add space